# Are there any SVN clients for Expression Blend?

Tags: svn, expression-blend

Is anyone aware of any SVN clients for Expression Blend? Maybe early days but it would be nice to have rather than continually switching back to Windows Explorer and using Tortoise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't AnhkSvn work with it?

In any case, [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) works with Expression Blend, [since v1.6](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/), its not free but at $50 its worth getting anyway.